# Emails to clients from Jira

Tags: email, jira, ticket-system

I'm looking to send out emails to clients when employees make progress on Jira tickets. Is that possible?

To give an example: A client sends a question through the company website. They then receive an email with their ticket number and can check back to see the status the ticket and/or receive emails to know when progress has been made on that ticket.

If it is possible, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If You have mail server connected with Jira enter **Notification schemes** in main administration. Create new scheme and choose for which event who should be notified. Then enter right project administration and in section **Notifications** connect created *Notification scheme* to this project. :)